# How to fill an empty dataframe with columns from a non-empty dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df template with only column names `df1` (0 observations), and I need to take values (entire columns) from `df2` to complete `df1`.

`df1` has id column name that I need to complete with SKU column from `df2`. But `df1` also has columns that I need to keep with `NA`s, for example: `df1$ios_url`.

I've tried:

```
df1$id <- df2$SKU
```

But got this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, id, value = c("0005CR", "0020MG", "0030HG",  : 
>         replacement has 7041 rows, data has 0

**df1**:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = character(0), title = character(0), ios_url = character(0), 
    ios_app_store_id = character(0), ios_app_name = character(0), 
    android_url = character(0), android_package = character(0), 
    android_app_name = character(0), windows_phone_url = character(0), 
    windows_phone_app_id = character(0), windows_phone_app_name = character(0), 
    description = character(0), google_product_category = character(0), 
    product_type = character(0), link = character(0), image_link = character(0), 
    condition = character(0), availability = character(0), price = character(0), 
    sale_price = character(0), sale_price_effective_date = character(0), 
    gtin = character(0), brand = character(0), mpn = character(0), 
    item_group_id = character(0), gender = character(0), age_group = character(0), 
    color = character(0), size = character(0), shipping = character(0), 
    custom_label_0 = character(0)), .Names = c("id", "title", 
"ios_url", "ios_app_store_id", "ios_app_name", "android_url", 
"android_package", "android_app_name", "windows_phone_url", "windows_phone_app_id", 
"windows_phone_app_name", "description", "google_product_category", 
"product_type", "link", "image_link", "condition", "availability", 
"price", "sale_price", "sale_price_effective_date", "gtin", "brand", 
"mpn", "item_group_id", "gender", "age_group", "color", "size", 
"shipping", "custom_label_0"), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", "collector"
    )), title = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ios_url = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ios_app_store_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), ios_app_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), android_url = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), android_package = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), android_app_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), windows_phone_url = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), windows_phone_app_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), windows_phone_app_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), description = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), google_product_category = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), product_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), link = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), image_link = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), condition = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), availability = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), price = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sale_price = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sale_price_effective_date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), gtin = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), brand = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), mpn = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), item_group_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), gender = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), age_group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), color = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), size = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), shipping = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), custom_label_0 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("id", "title", "ios_url", "ios_app_store_id", 
"ios_app_name", "android_url", "android_package", "android_app_name", 
"windows_phone_url", "windows_phone_app_id", "windows_phone_app_name", 
"description", "google_product_category", "product_type", "link", 
"image_link", "condition", "availability", "price", "sale_price", 
"sale_price_effective_date", "gtin", "brand", "mpn", "item_group_id", 
"gender", "age_group", "color", "size", "shipping", "custom_label_0"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

**DF2**:

```
df2 <- structure(list(TIENDA = c("CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", "CURACAO", 
"CURACAO", "CURACAO"), SKU = c("0005CR", "0020MG", "0030HG", 
"0055CC", "006029T-053-000", "006544WM-053"), NOMBRE = c("Parrilla Mr Grill Camping Redonda 31cm", 
"Parrilla Mr Grill Mini Grill + Maletín 31cm", "Parrilla Mr Grill Handy Grill 36cm", 
"Parrilla Mr Grill Cilíndrica Con Tapa", "Olla Arrocera Oster 006029T-053-000 1.8L - Turquesa", 
"Tostadora Oster 006544WM - Rojo"), PRECIO_OFERTA = c(39, 89, 
69, 169, 178.99, 99), PRECIO_LISTA = c(49, 129, 89, 169, 179, 
99), PRECIO_INDEXADO = c(39, 89, 69, 169, 178.9, 99), URLSEO = c("https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/parrilla-mr-grill-camping-redonda-31cm-0005cr", 
"https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/parrilla-mr-grill-mini-grill--maletín-31cm-0020mg", 
"https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/parrilla-mr-grill-handy-grill-36cm-0030hg", 
"https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/parrilla-mr-grill-cilíndrica-con-tapa-0055cc", 
"https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/olla-arrocera-oster-006029t-053-000-18l---turquesa--006029t-053-000", 
"https://www.lacuracao.pe/curacao/tostadora-oster-006544wm---rojo--006544wm-053"
), CATEGORIA_VENTA = c("Aire Libre", "Aire Libre", "Aire Libre", 
"Escápate de la Rutina", "Ollas Arroceras", "Oster"), CATEGORIA_MAESTRA = c("HEC0101MR", 
"HEC0101MR", "HEC0101MR", "HED0101MR", "APA1301OS", "APA1701OS"
), PUBLICADO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), ADQUIRIBLE = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FULLIMAGE = c("../efe_cat_as/646x1000/0005CR_1B.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/646x1000/0020MG_1.jpg", "../efe_cat_as/646x1000/0030HG_1B.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/646x1000/0055CC_1.jpg", "../efe_cat_as/646x1000/006029T-053-000_1.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/646x1000/006544WM-053_1.jpg"), THUMBNAIL = c("../efe_cat_as/200x310/0005CR_1B.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/200x310/0020MG_1.jpg", "../efe_cat_as/200x310/0030HG_1B.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/200x310/0055CC_1.jpg", "../efe_cat_as/200x310/006029T-053-000_1.jpg", 
"../efe_cat_as/200x310/006544WM-053_1.jpg"), MARCA = c("MR GRILL", 
"MR GRILL", "MR GRILL", "MR GRILL", "Oster", "Oster"), TAMAÑO = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "XS", "XS"), LASTUPDATE = structure(c(1525860198.288, 
1525860198.295, 1525860198.301, 1525860198.307, 1519742666.606, 
1519742666.61), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    MARCA_VERDE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), DIAS_VERDE = c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA), FIELD3 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), TIPO_VERDE = c("Y3", "Y3", "Y3", "Y3", NA, NA)), .Names = c("TIENDA", 
"SKU", "NOMBRE", "PRECIO_OFERTA", "PRECIO_LISTA", "PRECIO_INDEXADO", 
"URLSEO", "CATEGORIA_VENTA", "CATEGORIA_MAESTRA", "PUBLICADO", 
"ADQUIRIBLE", "FULLIMAGE", "THUMBNAIL", "MARCA", "TAMAÑO", "LASTUPDATE", 
"MARCA_VERDE", "DIAS_VERDE", "FIELD3", "TIPO_VERDE"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that `df1` should have as many rows as `df2` has.

Here is one approach that extracts the column names of `df1` in the first step. Then overwrites `df1` such that it only contains a single column `id`. This column will have the same observations as `df2`. We are now able to create all the columns from initial `df1` and fill them with `NA`s.

```
cols <- names(df1)
df1 <- data.frame(id = df2$SKU)
df1 <- `[<-`(df1, setdiff(cols, "id"), value = NA)
df1[, 1:4] # only printed the first four columns for illustration
#               id title ios_url ios_app_store_id
#1          0005CR    NA      NA               NA
#2          0020MG    NA      NA               NA
#3          0030HG    NA      NA               NA
#4          0055CC    NA      NA               NA
#5 006029T-053-000    NA      NA               NA
#6    006544WM-053    NA      NA               NA
```

Now we can replace other columns as well

```
df1$title <- df2$NOMBRE
```

Comment: Interesting approache, however, how could this work with multiple columns? I also need to extract column 'NOMBRE' and put it in df2 as 'title', and other columns.

Comment: @user3352567 Have edited my answer to address your question.